# Paypal MECL iOS - Show "Pay with a Card" View directly

Tags: ios, paypal

I am using the Paypal MECL library to process payments in my app.
On the screen showing all available payment methods I use the "Pay with Paypal" button from the Paypal library.
This leads the user to a UIWebView which loads the paypal site.
On this site at the very bottom there is a link called something like "Pay with a card", which loads another site where the user can also pay with a credit card.

I wonder if it is possible to initialize a UIWebView directly with the "Pay with a card" site.

Has anybody an idea how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the SetExpressCheckout call, you should be able to pass in the variable SOLUTIONTYPE=SOLE and this should make Pay with a card be the default.

By default, SOLUTIONTYPE will be MARK, which will show PayPal. So just setting this to SOLE should do the trick.